# Yarn - Why application attempt twice?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I made spark application which throw a error on purpose. When I ran this application on hadoop yarn, It always tried two times.

I want to run a application just once, not twice.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of application attempts is controlled by this property `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts`. This is **`2`** by default.

Modify this in `yarn-site.xml`,

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
   <value>1</value>
</property>
```

Comment: which node do i need to restart to apply this option?

Comment: ResourceManager.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks :)